# How to auto-incerment a specific column in mysql after creting the table

Tags: mysql

can anyone help me..

I have created a table without auto-incrementing the Sl.no (serial number), But now i want to auto-increment it. How can i do it.??

Comment: What have you tried? See [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) and [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

u need to alter it

```
alter table document modify column serial_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment
```

Comment: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key..., I'm getting this error when i alter the table.

Comment: your serial_id is not a primary key?

Comment: And i have not created any primary key.., Do i have to set any column as primary key?

Comment: you will need to use to again alter the table to set the primary key -  ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY myINdex (serial_id);

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE
        mytable
MODIFY  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Getting this error - ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE taggings MODIFY id INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: @Parthiv: you're running this command on PostgreSQL. This is a MySQL specific answer, it won't work on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this documentation page - [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html). Firstly, your field must be integer and primary key.

You may use a queries like this -

```
-- add AUTO_INCREMENT:
ALTER TABLE table
  CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

-- add primary key and AUTO_INCREMENT:
ALTER TABLE table
  CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Also, you can use one of MySQL GUI tools, for example - table editor in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition).

Comment: I have not created my sl.no as a primary key.., how can i assign now it as a primary key and also auto-increment it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your serial number column is not your table's primary key.  MySQL will not allow the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute to be assigned to a column which is not your primary key.

I can see two possible courses of action:

- Remove the Primary Key attribute from whatever other column might have it and add it to your serial number.  This will only work if the values in the Serial Number column are unique. Depending on how your table is setup, and how your Serial Number field is formatted, this could have adverse effects on the performance of subsequent queries on the table.

  ALTER TABLE [table] DROP PRIMARY KEY;

  ALTER TABLE [table] ADD [fieldname] [integer type] NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
- You can programatically fake the auto-increment by selecting the last (highest) value of the Serial Number column in your table (programatically) and incrementing it manually (also programatically) prior to your insert, and then simply insert it with the rest of your (new) record.

Comment: Thank u very much :) it works i deleted my serial number column by using syntax : ALTER TABLE [tablename] DROP [columnname] and later followed your syntax ALTER TABLE [table] ADD [fieldname] [integer type] NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;